# Wordpress. Проверить на родительство рубрики

Tags: wordpress

Есть рубрики

```
-Главная
--Дочерняя
---низ
```

Надо проверить что "низ" находится в дочерних рубриках в "главная"

Comment: get_category_parents( $id, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents

Получаете все категории для данной, и проверяйте находиться ли она в нужных вам.

Comment: Отлично, все работает)

Answer (score 9):

```
get_category_parents( $id, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents
Получаете все категории для данной, и проверяйте находится ли она в нужных вам.

<sub>Ответ перенесён из комментария</sub>